# Unexplained parenthesise in Java

Tags: java

What do parenthesis do in Java other than type casting.

I've seen them used in a number of confusing situations, [here's one from the Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html):

```
//convert strings to numbers
float a = (Float.valueOf(args[0]) ).floatValue();  
float b = (Float.valueOf(args[1]) ).floatValue();
```

I only know only two uses for parenthesis, calls, and grouping expressions. I have searched the web but I can't find any more information.

In the example above I know `Float.valueOF(arg)` returns an object. What effect does parenthesize-ing the object have?

Comment: Just because Oracle bought Sun doesn't mean they understand Java ;)

Comment: Actually, one would better write `float a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);` here, avoiding to create an unnecessary Float object only to throw it then away. But maybe this was the point of the example.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Or at the very least they could've relied on auto-unboxing and not call `floatValue()` at all.

Comment: @Paŭlo: parseFloat and the other parseXyz methods in the primitive wrappers were not introduced util Java 1.2. I bet I still have some old code using the Float.valueOf("47.11").floatValue() way.

Comment: I found the code [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)

Comment: @jarnbjo: They could still have updated the tutorials ... that were more than 10 years of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. In this case they are not necessary and can be removed. They are most likely there to make it more clear that `floatValue()` is called after `Float.valueOf()`.

So this is a case of parenthesis used to group expressions. Here it's grouping a single expression (which does obviously nothing).

It can be shortened to:

```
float a = Float.valueOf(args[0]).floatValue();
float b = Float.valueOf(args[1]).floatValue();
```

which can then be logically shortened to

```
float a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
float b = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
```

Comment: parseFloat is also faster as it doesn't create an object.

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe they serve any purpose here. Maybe left over after some refactoring

Answer (score 2):

None other than to confuse you. It's as good as saying

```
float a = Float.valueOf(args[0]).floatValue();
```

directly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the programmer just found it more readable. I don't agree with him in this particular case, but often use parentheses to make it clearer. For example, I find

```
int i = 3 + (2 * 4);
```

clearer than

```
int i = 3 + 2 * 4;
```

Comment: If you are using a language like Smalltalk, this effectively is different (first gives 11, the second gives 20).

Answer (score 0):

The extra parentheses in your code sample do not add anything.

```
//Your example:
        float a = (Float.valueOf(args[0]) ).floatValue();  

// equivalent:
        float a = Float.valueOf(args[0]).floatValue();
```

It could be that the original programmer had done something more elaborate within the parentheses and so had them for grouping, and neglected to remove them when simplifying the code. But trying to read intent into old source is an exercise in futility.

The extra space in `args[0]) )` is pretty odd looking, too, as it is unmatched in the opening paren.

Answer (score -1):

Here they are used for grouping. What's inside one of those expression if of type Float, so you can apply the method `floatValue()` to the whole content of the parenthesis.

They could be removed here as there is no ambiguity. They would have been mandatory with an expression using another operator of higher preseance order. But according [to the docs](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/what-is-java-operator-precedence.html), there is no such operator, the dot/projector has highest priority. So they are really useless here.

Regards,
 Stéphane